# Query with multiple SELECT statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to make a query containing 4 SELECT statements where each result is placed in its own column? How?

I'm currently sitting with 4 queries that I need to somehow combine into 1 and I've tried using UNION but it seems to put the results in the same column, just a new row.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to follow this pattern: select 1 as one, (select 2 from dual) as two from dual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sub-queries and a column alias:

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 Col1 From dbo.Table2 WHERE Condition1)AS Col1
,      (SELECT TOP 1 Col1 From dbo.Table3 WHERE Condition2)AS Col2
FROM dbo.Table1
```

[Using a Subquery in a T-SQL Statement](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3464481/Using-a-Subquery-in-a-T-SQL-Statement.htm)

Answer (score 2):

If the SELECT statements each return a SCALAR result, i.e. single-row, single-column - then yo can just do this:

```
SELECT (select .... ) Column1,
       (select .... ) Column2,
       (select .... ) Column3,
       (select .... ) Column4;
```

Comment: Would this work different if I needed to use SUM in all SELECT statements?

Comment: No it wouldn't. It's still the same flat pattern.